# Calculating the Energy density of a static spherically symmetric Boson Star in the Newtonian Approximation using the Energy momentum tensor

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-field-theory

I'm referring this paper [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Marcelo-Gleiser/publication/13277564_Gravitational_atoms_Gravitational_radiation_from_excited_boson_stars/links/53f1f4aa0cf272810e4c79cc/Gravitational-atoms-Gravitational-radiation-from-excited-boson-stars.pdf?_tp=eyJjb250ZXh0Ijp7ImZpcnN0UGFnZSI6InB1YmxpY2F0aW9uIiwicGFnZSI6InB1YmxpY2F0aW9uIn19) and I was trying to work out the calculation of the energy density which is the 00th element of the energy momentum tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$ which is given as:
$$
T_{\mu \nu}=\partial_\mu \Phi^* \partial_\nu \Phi+\partial_\nu \Phi^* \partial_\mu \Phi-\eta_{\mu \nu}\left(\eta^{\alpha \beta} \partial_\alpha \Phi^* \partial_\beta \Phi-m^2 \Phi^* \Phi\right)
$$
here, the metric tensor $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ is given by:
$$
\eta_{\mu\nu}=diag(1,-1,-r^2, -r^2sin^2\theta)
$$
I know that under the static spherically symmetric conditions, only the 00th element of the energy momentum tensor is non zero which is the energy density. In order to calculate it, I put $\mu=\nu=0$ along with $\alpha=\beta=0$. Upon calculating it, I got:
$$
T_{00}= m^2|\Phi|^2
$$
however, in the paper the energy density comes out to twice of what I got i.e. $T_{00}=2m^2|\phi|^2$. What am I doing wrong? Is this not how I am supposed to calculate the energy density in this particular case? Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *What am I doing wrong?* You are forgetting the contribution of spatial gradient of scalar field to the energy density.

Comment: Why did you set $\alpha=\beta=0$? These are contracted indices that you sum over.